# How to run function with two arguments (vectors of integers) without double for loop?

Tags: r, lapply

I have a function with two arguments (vectors of integers) and I want R to run it such that for each element in the first vector all elements of the second vector are processed. Here is a mock example:

```
n <- 1:10
mock_fun <- function(x, y) x + y
list1 <- lapply(n, mock_fun, x = 1) 
list2 <- lapply(n, mock_fun, x = 2)
list3 <- lapply(n, mock_fun, x = 3)
```

Now, suppose I want to use `k <- 1:100` to generate not only three lists, but a hundred lists. How to do it without a double for loop?

Comment: To end up with a matrix: `outer(n, 1:3, mock_fun)` or `outer(n, k, mock_fun)` for the `k <- 1:100`.

Comment: by `k <- 1:100` you mean `x` ? You want `y` from 1 to 10 and `x` from 1 to 100?

Comment: yes, but lmo already answered the question. If he were to make his comment an answer I would accept it.